# is this Epsilon-NFA correct?

Tags: state-machine

I am exercising and wasn't sure if I got this correct. I had to draw 0* U 1*. 
[image]

Update: This was correct

Comment: Yes this is correct ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yh you are right , This **`NFA`** accepts either **`0 or 1`** 
so you can say **`NFA`** for **`0 U 1`**

as epsilon concatenate with `1` results in **`1`**
or epsilon concatenate with `0` results in  **`0`**